# How can i transform my binary numpy list of arrays to an image?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 0 6 6 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 0 0 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]]
```

As a first step I want the pixels different than 0 to be white and the 0 pixels to be black.what i did to transform the none 0 values all to 1:

```
binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(bool).astype(int)
```

and it worked then i want to transform the list of arrays of 1s and 0s to image, what i tried:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.fromarray(binary_transform, '1')
img.save('image.png')
```

the docs for `Image.fromarray` can be found here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

It didn't work then i tried the following:

```
import png

png.from_array(binary_transform, 'L').save('image.png')
```

Referring to the docs `'L'` is for grayscale while i want binary but i didn't see a binary option, the docs https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html

and i got this error  `ValueError: bitdepth (64) must be a positive integer <= 16`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you don't say that explicitly, the fact that you said *"As a first step..."*, makes me think you are heading towards a greyscale palette image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
labels=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,6,6,6,6],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,5,5,5,0,0,5,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,6,6,0,0,6,6,6,0,0,6,6],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,6,6,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,6,6],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,6,6,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,6,6],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,0,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,6,6,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,6,6]]
binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(binary_transform, 'P')
img.save('image.png')
```

[image]

Note that I have resized and contrast-stretched the image for display purposes.

If you really only want a true binary, black and white image, use:

```
binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(np.uint8)
binary_transform[binary_transform>0] = 255
img = Image.fromarray(binary_transform, 'L')
img.save('image.png')
```

Comment: Actually no it's not a grayscale image, it's the output of the connected components  function applied to a grayscale image(`cv2.connectedComponents`)

Comment: I guessed that it was Connected Components labelling :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you want the image to appear binary, i.e., just black and white, no grey. If that's the case, OpenCV is your friend:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(np.uint8)

_,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(binary_transform, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite('image.png', thresh_img)
```

Of course PIL will work as well, you just need to adjust your non-zero values.

```
binary_transform = np.array(labels).astype(np.uint8)
binary_transform[binary_transform > 0] = 255

img = Image.fromarray(binary_transform, 'L')
img.save('image.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, and +1 for doing it two different ways!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers (all good!) use OpenCV or PIL.  Here's how you could create the image using [`numpngw`](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/), a small library that I wrote to create PNG files from numpy arrays.

First, here's my data for the example:

```
In [173]: x
Out[173]: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Create the image using `numpngw.write_png()`:

```
In [174]: import numpy as np

In [175]: import numpngw

In [176]: numpngw.write_png("foo.png", (np.array(x) > 0).astype(np.uint8), bitdepth=1)
```

Here's the image: [image]